# How can I make a node's scale constant when It's parent is scaled?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am creating a program where you can layout shapes in a stackpane, and move them by clicking and dragging the shapes. These shape configurations can be saved and loaded from files. I also want to be able to resize the window at will. This is where problems arise.

I tried many solutions to keep the shapes' position constant while making saving and loading configurations simple. What has worked best is doing some magic to bind the stackpane's scale so that it fills its parent, instead of binding its height and width properties.

This makes the shapes within the stackpane scale when the stackpane does and keeps their position constant, which is exactly what I want. However, within each shape is an imageview I use as a button that "locks" the shape, so it cannot be dragged and moved by the mouse. This imageview ALSO scales when the stackpane scales, which I do NOT want.

**In short**, because my stackpane's contents scale when it scales, I am led to believe when a region is scaled, all its children and their children are scaled as well. I am looking for a way to prevent this effect.

I tried using *setManaged(false)*, and putting the imageview in a container pane with *pane.setScaleShape(false)*, but neither worked. *setScaleShape(boolean)* looks like what I want to use, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Any help on how to use it properly, or another solution to this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary mistake is to put your shapes directly into a StackPane. The StackPane is a layout pane which positions children in a specific way but what you want is absolute positioning. So the easiest solution is to put a simple Pane into your StackPane and then add the shapes to this Pane. A Pane does not do any layout and keeps the positions that you specify.